# Convey intended thread type (IO, default, main) when declaring suspend function

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

When designing an API with a `suspend` function, sometimes I want to convey that this function *should* be called on, say, an IO thread.  Other times that it is *essential* to do so.

Often it seems obvious; for example a database call should be called using [`Dispatchers.IO`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html) but if it's an interface function, then the caller cannot assume this.

What is the best approach here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the `suspend` function really must run in a specific context, then declare it directly in the function body.

```
suspend fun doInIO() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

}
```

If the caller should be able to change the dispatcher, the function can add the dispatcher as a default parameter.

```
suspend fun doInIO(context: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO) = withContext(context) {

}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but what about in the case where it *should*? The other issue here is that what if the caller is using some other IO thread dispatcher?  This style would be forcing them to use Dispatchers.IO

Comment: Perhaps something like `suspend fun doSomething(dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO) = withContext(dispatcher) {...}` ?

Comment: Yes, if the caller should be able to change the dispatcher, your solution will be fine. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe it's clearer to only accept a dispatcher. Otherwise, it's not clear why the function is accepting a coroutineContext when it's already being called in a coroutineContext. By only accepting a dispatcher, then we are saying the current  coroutineContext is used but with only the dispatcher overridden.

Comment: I would stay with `CoroutineContext`. So the caller may decide to add some other stuff, like a coroutine exception handler. From my point of view, it gives no advantage to restrict the type to the dispatcher.

Answer (score 2):

There is no strict mechanism for contracts like that, so you are flexible with choosing the mechanism that suits you and your team.

1) Always use `withContext(Dispatcher.IO)`. This is both strict and performant, if a method is invoked from within `IO` context it will be [fast-path'ed](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/common/kotlinx-coroutines-core-common/src/Builders.common.kt#L136).

2) Naming/annotation-based conventions. You can make an agreement in the team that any method which ends with `IO` or has a specific annotation should be invoked with `Dispatchers.IO`. This approach works mostly in small teams and **only for project-private API**. Once you start exporting it as a library/module for other teams such contracts tend to be broken.

3) You can mix the previous approach with a validation:

```
suspend fun readFile(file: ...) {
    require(coroutineContext[ContinuationInterceptor] == Dispatcher.IO) {
      "Expected IO dispatcher, but has ${coroutineContext[ContinuationInterceptor]} instead"
    }
    // read file
}
```

But this validation works only if you are not wrapping IO dispatcher in some kind of delegate/proxy. In that case, you should make validation aware of such proxies, something like:

```
fun validateIoDispatcher(dispatcher: ContinuationInterceptor) {
    if (dispatcher is Dispatchers.IO) return
    if (dispatcher is ProjectSpecificIoDispatcher) return
    if (dispatcher is ProjectSpecificWrapperDispatcher) {
        validateIoDispatcher(dispatcher.delegate)
    } else {
        error("Expected IO dispatcher, but has $dispatcher")
    }
}
```

> I want to convey that this function should be called on, say, an IO thread. Other times that it is essential to do so.

Not sure what the difference is between "should" and "essential", but having these approaches in mind you can combine it with default method parameters such as `suspend fun probablyIO(dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO)` or more flexible naming/annotation conventions.